# aspx.net Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

Tags: c#, asp.net

The error is `strProductId = row0.Cells[1].Text;`. It shows:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Can someone explain what is wrong with the codes? Thank you.

```
//retrieve the product ID from the first row of the DetailsView
DetailsViewRow row0 = DetailsView2.Rows[0];
strProductId = row0.Cells[1].Text;

//extract the QuantityOnHand from the database - based on the product ID 

strSQLSelect = "SELECT pQty FROM Products WHERE pItemID = @ProductId"; 
cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQLSelect, mDB);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = strProductId; 
object oQty = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
intQuantityOnHand = (int)oQty
```

Comment: row0 doesn't have cells[1] element, did you check the cells in debugger

Comment: Please -->[edit]<-- your post - code is unreadable in the comments.

Comment: I have checked the cells, it looks fine.

Comment: @Kevin123 is it have the value in cells[1] and cells[1].Text. Also check the cells[1].text in vs debug

Answer (score 1):

Please check the value of `row0.Cells[1].Text` row0.Cells don't have the array index 1. Please debug the below code.

```
DetailsViewRow row0 = DetailsView2.Rows[0];
if(row0.cell.count > 0)
{
  strProductId = row0.Cells[1].Text; 
}
```